# Tow replicas awx on k8s

Tags: kubernetes, ansible-awx

I deployed one replica of awx using the instalation role in repo of the the project. then i scales the statfulset of AWX to 2 replicas. but when i tail the the logs of the pods for example awx-0 and awx-1 they are both recieving the same request at the same time the web service doesn't load balance requests.

Comment: How are you establishing that they are receiving the same request at the same time? And through what mechanism are you connecting to them? Ingress controller? NodePort? Other?

Comment: i am conecting to them through an ingress controller, i knew that they are recieving and responding to the same requests at the same time by tailing logs  : kubectl logs awx-0  awx-web -f
and  kubectl logs awx-1 awx-web  -f

Comment: right, but given how suspicious that statement is, I meant for you to share with us the evidence you have of that behavior

Comment: i found the cause, AWX in HA mode forward all requests to all nodes. k8s dend  a request to one node this later duplcate the requets i do not know how.